# is it possible to use different enum types as non type template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, enums

Background:

I want to create types from enum values to handle them in connection with boost::sml.

So I want to create a type simply by giving the enum value like:

```
template <typename ENUM_T, ENUM_T VAL >
class Bla
{
};

enum A
{
    a1,
    a2
};

enum B
{
    b1,
    b2
};

int main()
{
    Bla<A::eins> x;
}
```

But this can't work as I have to define the type of the enum value before the non type template parameter which uses this enum type.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from C++17 it is possible to utilize non-type template parameters with automatic type deduction:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <auto val>
class Bla
{
    static_assert(::std::is_enum_v<decltype(val)>); // constraint parameter types to enums
};
```

Prior to C++17 you will need to supply non-type parameter type as another template parameter:

```
template <typename T, T val>
class Bla
…
Bla<A, A::eins> x;
```

Comment: Cool! Any chance on C++14 as our project uses outdated compilers? But good to know the c++17 stuff, so I do not want to tag my question as C++14.

Comment: So the answer is "No" until c++17. The handcrafted passed type is clear ;) Thanks!